# remove discount code form from checkout page magento2?

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, forms, discount

In my custom theme i do not use discount form. In cart, I removed via xml and it works. But in checkout I can't remove it via xml.

How i can **remove discount form in onepage checkout**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable the component in your `checkout_index_index.xml`, we can use the following instructions:

```
<item name="%the_component_to_be_disabled%" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Read more: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html#disable-a-component

*app/code/Vendor/Checkout/view/layout/checkout_index_index.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <!--Disable Discount here-->
                                                                <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

We can remove a component from layout rendering via Plugin also.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I put the code from <referenceBlock> inside the <body> tag as one of <referenceBlock>s  , I have even tried to flush cache and deploy static. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Remove the Apply Coupon Code Field at the checkout & cart page  in Magento 2.3**

**step 1 : Remove from checkout/cart demo** => http://abc/checkout/cart/
GO with your child theme file path

> app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

simply write below line

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.coupon" remove="true"/>
```

or else go with another below path :

> app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

simply write same line

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.coupon" remove="true"/>
```

**step 2 : Remove from checkout/payment** => http://abc/checkout/#payment

copy this file from your `vendor/magento/module-salesrule/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

**Overwrite above vendor file to your child theme :**

> app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Magento_SalesRule/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

find this code (line no approx :24) in your file.

```
<item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
```

**Now removed item discount by below code. You need to simply put this lines**

```
   <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
   </item>
```

**done...**